# Java Library or algorithm for calculating coordinates of tree nodes / drawing

Tags: java, tree, drawing, coordinate

I am looking for a library which would give me the **exact coordinates of each node** in a tree (any tree, not just binary trees).

Let's say I define the tree in the following notation

```
(() (() (() () ()))
```

And some library gives me the coordinates like this:

```
[500 0]([200 50]() [600 50]([500 100]() [750 100]([600 150]() [700 150]() [800 150]()))
```

or any other notation which uniquely represents a tree.

This kind of library would enable a space-efficient drawing of trees and would also solve the problem of overlapping nodes and links. For example, if a tree is a list infact, I would like that library to take that into account and arrange nodes in a single column or row, to save space.

If nothing similar exists, **an algorithm would also come in handy**, provided that it can be implemented relatively easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Nested Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) model may help you.

The algorithm is fairly simple, and very efficient for reads, although updates to the tree are a little more expensive, because the boundaries of the nodes have to be updated in a cascading fashion. [Here is the algorithm implemented in SQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).